# JavaScript countdown timer with on key press to reset the timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to work out how when I press a key it counts down from 30 to 0, and if i press that key again it does the same thing, counts from 30 to 0 (resets).

Is there some way this is can be done with JavaScript and in the HTML only have it displaying the numbers counting from 30 to 0 with no other text?

I have tried using other examples however I think i must be putting the script into the wrong place. Is someone able to give me an example not just of the JS but also what the HTML markup should look like? Would be much appreciated.

The example I have been trying to modify and play with is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>JavaScript in Body</h2>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    $(function() {

      var perc = 50 // User will be logged out after (minutes)
      var count = perc * 60;

      // RESET TIMER

      $(document).keypress(function() {
        var count = perc * 60; // PROBLEM
        alert('keypress works');
      });

      //COUNTDOWN

      var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

      function timer() {
        count = count - 1;
        if (count == -1) {
          // LOGOUT //
          return;
        }

        var seconds = count % 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);

        seconds %= 60;
        minutes %= 60;

        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById("start_time").innerHTML = inactive;
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the naive approach for a one-second countdown using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), which calls its parameter function after at least `n` milliseconds (1000 ms = 1s) elapses.

```js
/* an inaccurate counter */
let count;
let interval;
const timer = document.querySelector("#timer");

document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.code === "KeyX") {
    clearInterval(interval);
    count = 30;
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      timer.innerText = count--;

      if (count < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="timer">press "x" key</div>
```

The problem here is that the 1000 ms provided to `setTimeout` is a *minimum* delay between calls. Delays beyond 1000 ms will accumulate and cause drift.

Consider using a [date/time library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) if precision is important. [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) can also be handy to ensure that no renders are missed and that changes to the countdown (such as a reset event) reflect to the user interface quickly.

To keep scope clean, we can use a closure to initialize and run the counter loop. This countdown initializer can return a function to stop the counter, invocable by an event handler.

```js
const runCountdown = (counter, el) => {
  let start = Date.now() / 1000;
  let running = true;

  (function tick() {
    const elapsed = Date.now() / 1000 - start;
    el.innerText = Math.max(0, counter - Math.floor(elapsed));

    if (running && elapsed < counter) {
      requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
  })();
  
  return () => (running = false);
};

let stop; 
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.code === "KeyX") {
    stop?.();
    stop = runCountdown(30, document.querySelector("#count"));
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Press the "x" key to start or restart the countdown.</p>
<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What if I wanted it set for a specific key say letter X as opposed to any key. Would i need to use something like

.keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 114)

provided i lookup the correct key code?

Comment: Thanks mate!

first box is the java script which I need to put into the <script> tags?, second box is the style.css? 

Does that DIV go into the body of the html file?

Comment: Yep, JS goes into `<script>` tags and should be at the end of your body or is externally referenced from `<script>`. The style isn't important in my example but would go in `<style>` tags in the header or external in `style.css` with a link pointing to it.

Comment: Ohhh SNAP mate! I got it, I just couldn't get my head around it, even after looking at all the examples - I get what you mean by the CSS portion isn't that important but I now understand its relevance. In this instance I won't need the CSS THANK YOU VERY MUCH, you have taught me alot just by helping me understand the HTML markup - In my books; you win the internet today, mich love xx

Comment: Don't suppose you know if javascript is able to/smart enough to select what window to capture the keystroke in? What  I'm doing is importing the htm file into stemaing software and want to be in a game, when I press the key it should kick off the timer thats imported as a html file. This import works and the text is displayed to press they key but it only recognizes the physical key press when the html file is open in the web browser.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be an active window as far as I know. You might open a new question for that and/or do some research.