# Using setInterval and clearInterval to start and stop file reload via HTML input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I need help to using `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to start and stop a file reload via an HTML input checkbox.

Currently, it's reloading the file every 10 seconds which is good. But now I need to change it so that if I remove the tick mark from the checkbox it should stop reloading and stay as it is until I tick it again it should start reloading again.

By default it should be ticked so it only stops when I need.

HTML Code:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"  name="refresh" id="refresh"
        checked="checked"/>
  refresh
</label>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function auto_load() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "//www.example.com/test.php?id=123",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      $(".test").html(data);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  auto_load();
});

//Refresh auto_load() function after 10000 milliseconds
setInterval(auto_load, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the return value of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to manipulate the timer:

> The returned `intervalID` is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to `setInterval();` this value can be passed to `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearInterval()` to cancel the timeout.

We can also use a jQuery change listener on the checkbox element to listen for toggles. Whenever we hear a change on the element, we can toggle the interval on and off based on its value (nonzero id if running or `undefined` if not).

Here's a proof-of-concept. I sped up the refresh rate and used a mock API request.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function autoload() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d8f70953200005600adec34',
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function (data) {
        $(".test").html(data + " " + requestNumber++);
      }
    });
  }

  var refreshRate = 1000;
  var requestNumber = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(autoload, refreshRate);
  
  $('#refresh').change(function () {
    if (interval) {
      interval = clearInterval(interval);      
    }
    else {
      autoload();
      interval = setInterval(autoload, refreshRate);
    }
  });
  
  autoload();
});
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"  
         name="refresh" 
         id="refresh"
         checked="checked" />
  refresh
</label>
<div class="test"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `setInterval` only guarantees a minimum delay before a callback fires, which isn't reliable for accurate timing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665348/6243352) for an example of using [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to improve accuracy if that's important for this application.

Comment: its working but when i refresh page it never rest to default checked in input field if i uncheck it and refresh the page on refresh it remains same unchecked. so if i make it checked it stops refreshing and when i make it unchecked it starts refreshing, means to say whole process gets reversed on check button.

Comment: ok i found the issue i have added  autocomplete="off" to input and its fine now