# Javascript Counter Troubleshooting - Button Question

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I made a question yesterday.

I am able now to get the `console.log` to show the two minute timer going down.
When I try adding this logic to a button in my code I am given this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: minutes is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

```
const startingMinutes = 2
    let time = startingMinutes * 60

    let timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)

    function countDown() {
        const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
        let seconds = time % 60
        time--
        console.log(minutes, 'minutes:', seconds, 'seconds');

        if (time <= 0) {
            console.log('Time is up!');
            clearInterval(timerId)
        }
    }

 button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        countDown()
        countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + seconds + ' seconds '
    })
```

I know minutes is defined in the function, when I try making the variable outside the function my code does not decrement. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any tips on where to start would be helpful, thank you everyone for viewing and helping!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yeah, you'd need to expose the variable to both scopes. That said, the design has a few fundamental flaws. `setTimeout` isn't reliable. I suggest using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665348/6243352)

Answer (score 1):

So you can make a little change and try this

```
const startingMinutes = 2;
let minutesInSecond = startingMinutes*60;
let myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');//button id on which you start timer
let counter = document.getElementById('counter');// tag where you want to show timer's value

function countDown(){// inside this we handle all things
let currentMinutes = startingMinutes;
let currentSeconds = 0;
counter.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + currentSeconds + ' seconds '
let id = setInterval(()=>{
    minutesInSecond--;
    currentMinutes = Math.floor(minutesInSecond/60);
    currentSeconds = minutesInSecond%60;
    counter.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + currentSeconds + ' seconds ';
    if(minutesInSecond == 0){
        clearInterval(id);
        console.log('Time is up!');
    }
},1000);}

myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    countDown();/call this function when user click**strong text**});
```

Comment: apart from these you should make button disabled when we click for first time other many interval id created and unexpected beahaviour can occur

Answer (score 0):

when you declare a variable inside a function, that variable is not reachable from outside that function. So in this case what you'd have to do is move the line `countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + seconds + ' seconds '` inside the `countDown` function like this:

```
  const startingMinutes = 2
  let time = startingMinutes * 60
  let timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)
  function countDown() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    let seconds = time % 60
    time--
    console.log(minutes, 'minutes:', seconds, 'seconds');
    if (time <= 0) {
      console.log('Time is up!');
      clearInterval(timerId)
    }
    countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + seconds + ' seconds '
  }
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    countDown()
  })
```